# How to redirect a part of stderr and stdout to /dev/null

Tags: grep, redirection, pipe, stdout, stderr

My program outputs to `stderr` and `stdout`. I want to grep for "pattern" either in `stderr` and `stdout`. And I want the rest to be sent to `/dev/null`.

If I pipe after redirect `stderr` : `./prog 2>/dev/null | grep "pattern"`
I don't get the lines of `stderr` that contain "pattern".

If I pipe before redirecting `stderr` : `./prog | grep "pattern" 2>/dev/null`
none of `stderr` is redirected to `/dev/null`

thank you for your help.

Comment: *If I pipe before redirecting stderr : ./prog | grep "pattern" 2>/dev/null none of stderr is redirected to /dev/null*: and how is this bad?

Comment: I would like only the lines containing "pattern" to be visible. Not all of stderr.

Comment: This is what you get with `/prog | grep "pattern"` automatically.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: no, an ordinary pipe ("|") only forwards stdout to the next process. stderr would pass "sideways" and show up completely (unfiltered) in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you do not care whether the string match originates from stdout or stderr, then just merge the two streams by redirecting stderr to stdout, then do the grep:

```
$ your_program 2>&1 | grep "pattern"
```

the example works in sh, bash, ksh, zsh.
csh should be:

```
$ your_program |& grep "pattern"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
./prog 2>&1 | grep pattern
```

You must see only the lines containing "pattern"